# Should I commit my `.idea/` folder?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

Should I commit my idea folder in git and in remote version controls like Github? Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 45):

I wouldn't commit any specific IDE configuration into the repository.

2 important reasons are:

1. IDE configuration almost always involves absolute paths in disk, where different users may not have the same...
2. You don't want to constraint all users to use the same IDE config...

Comment: What about code formatting? Code style? Copyright info? This is present in the .idea folder..

Comment: @downvoter: any particular reason why the downvote?

Comment: @nhaarman: if by code formatting you mean tools like jslint etc (code style...) those have separate configs which should be persisted to the repository.

Comment: Just ignore .idea/workspace.xml and .idea/libraries

Comment: This opinion is one of the things that make the Java development ecosystem a nightmare of yak shaving.

Comment: It seems like this is informed in the spirit of FOSS projects where one will have a lot of heterogeneous developer workflows.  Should this advice apply to teams that all use the same tooling?

Comment: Not that I'm advocating for committing .idea dirs, but your assumptions are wrong. 1) .idea directories do not contain any absolute paths, only relative ones. 2) .idea directories don't contain any configs, they only contain discovery caches.