# What files need to be added to version control for a react-native project's continuous integration pipeline?

Tags: react-native, version-control, gitignore, visual-studio-app-center

I'm adding my react-native project to version control. My intent is to configure a continuous integration pipeline using Microsoft's AppCenter.

When I try to push my project to GitHub, there are a few files that are too large. One is a file in the iOS/Pods directory, the other is a .hprof file In the android directory.

Im hard-pressed to find a quality explanation of what files need to be included in version control for these ci/cd pipelines.

currently my .gitignore (taken from https://www.gitignore.io/api/reactnative) looks like:

```
### ReactNative ###
# React Native Stack Base
### ReactNative.Xcode Stack ###
# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated
build/
DerivedData/

## Pods
ios/Pods/ <- can this be ignored and still have successful CI builds?

## Various settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata/

## Other
*.moved-aside
*.xccheckout
*.xcscmblueprint

### ReactNative.Node Stack ###
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# nyc test coverage
.nyc_output

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# Bower dependency directory (https://bower.io/)
bower_components

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules/
jspm_packages/

# Typescript v1 declaration files
typings/

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional eslint cache
.eslintcache

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history

# Output of 'npm pack'
*.tgz

# Yarn Integrity file
.yarn-integrity

# dotenv environment variables file
.env


### ReactNative.Buck Stack ###
buck-out/
.buckconfig.local
.buckd/
.buckversion
.fakebuckversion

### ReactNative.macOS Stack ###
*.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk

### ReactNative.Gradle Stack ###
.gradle
**/build/

# Ignore Gradle GUI config
gradle-app.setting

# Avoid ignoring Gradle wrapper jar file (.jar files are usually ignored)
!gradle-wrapper.jar

# Cache of project
.gradletasknamecache

# # Work around https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116898
# gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

### ReactNative.Android Stack ###
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# Intellij
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json

### ReactNative.Linux Stack ###
*~

# temporary files which can be created if a process still has a handle open of a deleted file
.fuse_hidden*

# KDE directory preferences
.directory

# Linux trash folder which might appear on any partition or disk
.Trash-*

# .nfs files are created when an open file is removed but is still being accessed
.nfs*

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/reactnative
```

Im not sure which files can be ignored, and which NEED to exist in version control so AppCenter can build the project. for example, can iOS/Pods be excluded from VC? why/why not etc. for initial commit, my untracked files are:

```
.buckconfig
 .eslintrc.js
 .firebaserc
 .flowconfig
 .gitignore
 .idea/
 .prettierrc.js
 .watchmanconfig
 App.js
 __tests__/
 android/
 app.json
 babel.config.js
 firebase.json
 functions/
 index.android.js
 index.js
 ios/
 metro.config.js
 package-lock.json
 package.json
 src/
```

For the initial commit, which do and which dont need to be added to VC?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm trying to figure out the same thing

Comment: i believe you can exclude .idea/...everything else in that list youll want to keep

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers of this question, you can pretty do your first commit and just let the `.gitignore` (automatically with `react-native init`) handle the first commit. Then add the untracked config files in the next commit. If you don't have the `.gitignore` you can grab it from the React Native git [repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/template/_gitignore) or here:

```
# OSX
#
.DS_Store

# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate

# Android/IntelliJ
#
build/
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml
*.hprof

# node.js
#
node_modules/
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# BUCK
buck-out/
\.buckd/
*.keystore
!debug.keystore

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the
# screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/source-control/

*/fastlane/report.xml
*/fastlane/Preview.html
*/fastlane/screenshots

# Bundle artifact
*.jsbundle

# CocoaPods
/ios/Pods/
```

My untracked files looked like this after my initial commit:

```
.buckconfig
.cvsignore.txt
.editorconfig
.eslintrc.js
.flowconfig
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.prettierrc.js
.watchmanconfig
babel.config.js
metro.config.js
tsconfig.json
```

and I ended up including all of them as per OP's suggestions. IDE specific folders like .vscode and .idea folders can also be excluded [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764319/should-i-commit-my-idea-folder). Some other big ones that should be ignored are the `Pods`, and `node_modules` folders as they are automatically generated when you run `pod install` and `yarn`/`npm install` respectively.